# Reset Windows 10 Professional Password while I cannot boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, passwords

I have kind of chicken-and-egg delimma. Yesterday, all of a sudden, my Dell XPS 15 did not boot properly, and showed the error **"The digital signature for this file could not be verified for this file. Error code: 0xc0000428"**. What magnifies my problem is I forgot my admin password (only account on this machine) as I have been using fingerprint for more than 2 years now. However, I cannot reach the figerprint screen anymore with this boot error. Here is what I tried:

1. Used Boot USB to start repair. It redirects me to choose account, then I am blocked because I do not remember the password
2. Change my MS password online (it is "outlook" account). It still does not accept the new password. I am wondering if it is because I do not reach the sign-in screen, it only checks against the last used local password!
3. Tried the ulitman trick. It did not work, and it will not help because I can't reach the login screen to utilize the utility manager to change the password
4. To fix the error of "The digital signature ..." I tried to disable that from Startup options. When I click "restart" it does not take me to startup options where I can disable the digital signature enforcement (with F7), but it takes me to the original error screen.

Comment: Local account or MS account?

Comment: If you are using a fingerprint, chances are great that it is a Microsoft Account. Go to Microsoft Account on the web, Login, and then use the Forgot Password routine

Comment: “The digital signature ...” what error are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @JohannesH. How to tell? It is with "outlook" domain. So it is MS account right?

Comment: @John I changed my MS password online, but it is still not accepting the new password on my machine. I wonder if it is because it does not reach the sign-in screen and therefore does not check the online password but rather the last used local password (guessing)

Comment: Can you get your documents (or have a backup) and then re-install Windows?

Comment: @John I have a backup. I have two issues with this options: First I have hundreds of software and configurations on this machine. If I re-install, it will take me ages to be up to speed again. Second, Factory reset request for the password!!

Comment: On the second issue, a Microsoft Account will work when reinstalling Windows 10.

Comment: Just for future visitors' reference, I decided today to format my machine based on the advise from dell agent (initially asked me to try all things I mentioned above). Also reset password software I purchased did not work : iSunshare & neoSmart EasyBCD (waste of money!)